# How to define multiple indices for Gurobi with Python API where indices are of different data types and depend on each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-programming, gurobi

I'm quite new to Gurobi and Python and I came across a following problem. Given are sets:

```
import pandas as pd

I = pd.DataFrame(index = ['i0', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4'])

L = [('k0', 'j2'), ('k0', 'j3'), ('k0', 'j4'), ('k1', 'j3'), ('k2', 'j1'), ('k2', 'j2'), ('k2', 'j4')]

N_i = {'i0': [('k0', 'j4')],'i1': [('k0', 'j3'), ('k1', 'j3')],
 'i2': [],'i3': [('k0', 'j2'), ('k0', 'j3'), ('k0', 'j4'), ('k2', 'j2'), ('k2', 'j4')],
 'i4': [('k0', 'j4')]}

theta = {'i0': 27, 'i1': 36, 'i2': 31, 'i3': 14, 'i4': 41}
```

I have to define the following objective function and constraint:

[image]

I tried to do something like this in different variations, but it didn't work.

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import itertools

model1 = gp.Model('Location-allocation problem 1')
x_ikj = model1.addVars(list(itertools.product(I.index, L)), vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = 'x_ikj')
model1.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(x_ikj[i, k, j]
            for (k, j) in N_i[i]) >= theta[i] for i in I.index)
```

Do you have any ideas how can I formulate such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you defined the index tuple of x_ikj as (i, (k, j)) rather than (i, k, j). In fact, `itertools.product` is unnecessary since gurobipy.Model.addVars() does the cross-product for you. So the simple fix is to write:

```
x_ikj = model1.addVars(I.index, L, vtype = GRB.INTEGER, name = 'x_ikj')
```

Additionally, it looks like you're mixing a Pandas DataFrame (for I) with Python built-in data types for L. This is not common; people typically pick one data type or the other.